# Promises, setting a var on return, then executing a function?

Tags: jquery

I have a promise:

```
var promise = getNumContentTotal(ctx);
```

The above returns the total number of content from my database. I then wish to set a var to hold this information.

So I have done:

```
promise.done(function(data){
    ctx.numContentTotal = data;
});
```

Q1. Is there a better way to do this? Should vars be set on done, or should they be in the success callback of the ajax function?

After I set the numContentTotal I wish to call another ajax call.

I have done:

```
promise.done(getContentAll(ctx));
```

Q2. But this gets called before I set my var, numContentTotal and I need this var in the getContentAll function.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `promise.done(getContentAll(ctx));` this executes the function immediately. You can use an anonymous function that receives the response and then inside that call your `getContentAll(ctx)`

Comment: You need to do `promise.done(function(data){ ctx.numContentTotal = data; getContentAll(ctx); })`.  You need to pass a *function* to done.  When you do `promise.done(getContentAll(ctx));` you are calling `getContentAll` then passing its return value to `.done`.